# Incrementing version then pushing change to Git before MsBuild kicks off

Tags: git, powershell, msbuild

I have three separate MVC websites in one solution and I'm trying to improve the release process for them. Prior to my release build kicking off I would like to increment the version in the shared version file then push this change using Git. I have a powershell script that increments the version and it's working well but I can't find out how to push these changes as part of the build.

Any help or advice would be great.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make that part of the release build. Add a targets for incrementing the version number and pushing the repository, and make your release target depend on them:

```
<Target Name="IncrementVersion">
  <Exec Command="powershell.exe -File C:\path\to\your.ps1" />
</Target>

<Target Name="PushRepo">
  <Exec Command="git push ..." />
</Target>

<Target Name="Release" DependsOnTargets="IncrementVersion; PushRepo">
  ...
</Target>
```

Building a target will cause its dependencies to be built first, [in the order they appear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx) (left to right).

Both the `PushRepo` and the `IncrementVersion` target execute external commands (`git.exe` and `powershell.exe` respectively) via the `<Exec>` element. In case of the `PushRepo` target this means that Git must be installed and `git.exe` must be in the PATH of whatever system you're building the target on. If Git is installed, but the executable is not in the PATH, you need to specify the full path to the executable in the `Command` attribute.

Note that `push` will only push already committed changes to the upstream repository. To include the changes made via the `IncrementVersion` target you must issue a `commit` first.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I'm using the default git template to carry out my build. Will it recognise the git commands? Will I need to install anything on the server side? Lastly I'm assuming that it will pick up the change from increment version, if so is it a case of just calling git commit and git push? Sorry for the multitude of questions I've only recently moved over to Git!